# Yoneda extension and splittings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $X$ be a non-singular algebraic variety and $F$ be a coherent sheaf defined over $X$. Suppose that we have a locally free resolution
$$0 \to L_n \xrightarrow{f_n} L_{n-1} \to ... \to L_0 \to F \to 0$$
of $F$. If $\mbox{Ext}^i(F,L_n)=0$ for all $i \ge n$, does it mean that there exists a morphism $g_n:L_{n-1} \to L_n$ such that $g_n \circ f_n$ is identity? We know this is true for $n=1$.

I know that $\mbox{Ext}^n(F,L_n)$ parametrizes all Yoneda extensions of length $n$ with final object $F$ and initial object $L_n$. However, I am unable to find a precise definition of trivial extension for $n>1$ i.e., the zero object of $\mbox{Ext}^n(F,L_n)$. The logical guess is one where there exists $g_n$ as mentioned above, but I am not sure.

Comment: If you can use that resolution to compute Ext then definitely yes, it would actually suffice triviality for $i=n$.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Can you suggest a reference (especially for the definition of the trivial object of $Ext^n$ for $n>1$, in terms of Yoneda extensions)?

Comment: Well, I was just thinking that if the cokernel of $Hom(f_n, L_n)$ is zero then any map out of $L_n$ factors through $f_{n}$. Characterizing the trivial (higher) extension may be tricky in general.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Thanks, I think I understand.